# How can I pass a class with properties to a WPF modal Window, modify it, and get the class back to the parent window?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Forgive me if I get some terminology wrong.  I’m going to simplify my problem a bit to target the specific piece I’m struggling with.

Scenario:  I have a WPF window that I want to pass a class with properties to a WPF modal window, modify a property of the class that was passed to the modal window, and then pass the class with the update back to the original WPF modal window.

For testing/diagnostic purposes, I’m setting a value of one of the properties in the class before sending it to the modal WPF Window, and trying to bind that property to a textbox in the WPF Modal window, but I haven’t had luck.  (I have shown a message box after initializing the WPF modal window showing a property of the class I manually set and it shows it, so I know the class is at least being passed to the WPF modal window, but it isn’t displaying, and I don’t know if it will pass back to the parent form if I were able to change it. )

For an example, the parent form is a basic address form, and I want to display a series of WPF modal windows to get each value so the use can type the value, press enter, and have a new window pop up for the next value.  (In the real world application, many of the potential fields will be pre-populated, and if it Is, it won’t display to the user, so out of a potential 50 windows, the user may only need to see 5 to 10, but it will vary depending on what was pre-populated.)

I am displaying the WPF Modal Window with this code:

```
public void OpenFirstNameWindow(Person person)
{

    FirstNameWindow FirstNameWindow_Child = new FirstNameWindow(person);

    FirstNameWindow_Child.Owner = this;
    FirstNameWindow_Child.ShowDialog();
}
```

For the text box I’ve tried both of these for binding

Text="{Binding FirstName}"

Text="{Binding person.FirstName}"

Neither work.   I need help passing a class to, and getting it back from, a WPF modal window.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to apply person to DataContext, eg( FirstNameWindow_Child.DataContext = person) and then use binding using first option. It also depends if all other code is correct. Please attach full xaml and code-behind the FirstNameWindow .

Comment: Ed Plunkett, you sir, are a life saver.